# Python-mock: mocking pymongo's Cursor and Collection in the same test case

Tags: python, mongodb, mocking, pymongo, python-mock

I want to make a mock test for some mongo queries, but I had a problem when I tried to mock two diferent mongo objects (Cursor and Collection) in the same scope.
I can't put the original code here, but I made a generic with the same problem.

This is the function I want to test (using find and distinct):

```
def get_some_info(date1, date2):
    data = collection.find({"timestamp": {"$lt": date1, "$gt": date2})
    id_list = data.distinct("id")

    for id in id_list :
       collection.find({"id" : id})
```

This is the test code:

```
@mock.patch.object(Collection, "find")
@mock.patch.object(Cursor, "distinct")
def test_get_some_info(self, mock_distinct, mock_find):
    date1 = datetime.datetime()
    date2 = datetime.datetime()
    mock_distinct.return_value = ["id1", "id2"]
    find_parameters1 = {"timestamp": {"$lt": date1, "$gt": date2}
    find_parameters2 = {"id" : "id1"}
    self.my_class.get_some_info(date1, date2)
    mock_find.assert_called_with(find_parameters1)
    mock_find.assert_any_call(find_parameters2)
```

When I run the test, I have this error message:

> '%s call not found' % expected_string AssertionError: find({"id" :
>   "id1"}) call not found

So I printed the value of id_list:

```
def get_some_info(date1, date2):
    data = collection.find({"timestamp": {"$lt": date1, "$gt": date2})
    id_list = data.distinct("id")
    print id_list

    for id in id_list :
        collection.find({"id" : id})
```

This is the value of id_list:

> MagicMock name='find().distinct()' id='139719585597776'

But the expected is: ["id1", "id2"]

When I comment the Cursor's mock, the value of id_list is the same as before:

```
#@mock.patch.object(collection, "distinct")
@mock.patch.object(Cursor, "find")
def test_get_some_info(self, mock_find):
    date1 = datetime.datetime()
    date2 = datetime.datetime()
    mock_distinct.return_value = ["id1", "id2"]
    find_parameters1 = {"timestamp": {"$lt": date1, "$gt": date2}
    find_parameters2 = {"id" : "id1"}
    self.my_class.get_some_info(date1, date2)
    mock_find.assert_called_with(find_parameters1)
    mock_find.assert_any_call(find_parameters2)

<MagicMock name='find().distinct()' id='140089689306448'>
```

I think the code is always catching the "distinct" value from Collection, not from Cursor.
Does anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. mocks objects in test arguments should be in the reverse order (take a look to [Nesting Patch Decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#nesting-patch-decorators) for details)
2. What you called `mock_collection` should be `mock_find`

Your test code should be this:

```
@mock.patch.object(Cursor, "distinct")
@mock.patch.object(Collection, "find")
def test_get_some_info(self, mock_find, mock_distinct):
    date1 = datetime.datetime()
    date2 = datetime.datetime()
    mock_distinct.return_value = ["id1", "id2"]
    find_parameters1 = {"timestamp": {"$lt": date1, "$gt": date2}
    find_parameters2 = {"id" : "id1"}
    self.my_class.get_some_info(date1, date2)
    mock_find.assert_called_with(find_parameters1)
    mock_find.assert_any_call(find_parameters2)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, it was my mistake. In my original code, the decorators' order are correct. I changed the parameters now

Comment: @DiegoPereira please explain what `mock_connection` is in your example

Comment: Take a look to your log: `connection` is a mock and you call `find`'s mock method

Comment: It was my mistake again, mock_collection is the mock_find in the original source code. I fixed it. I think the problem is more related to "distinct" is both method of Cursor and Collection.
Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: Your log say `data.distinct("id")` is a mock where name is `find().distinct()` that means `data` is `find()`'s return value on a mock -> in `get_some_info()` `collection` **IS** a mock. Now in your posted code I cannot understand what `collection` is and why it is a mock. That is why we should avoid to post toy code in our questions.